# In what situations will a refresh token be revoked/invalidated?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am wondering what situations a refresh token can cause a refresh token to be revoked.
A Microsoft Account changing their password? Multiple invalid login attempts on a Users account?

Comment: you can find the answer to your question here I think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Answer (score 1):

There are different reasons, you could refer to the [**Token revocation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#token-revocation).

[image]